# react-native-maps: How do I add markers without re-rendering the entire map?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps-android-api-2, react-native-maps

I'm building a map that displays markers to show the location of nearby merchants. I'm passing a 'data' array as props to the map. I've set an interval such that every two seconds, I fetch more merchants from my API, and the 'data' array grows.

I'm fetching the data inside componentWillReceiveProps. fetchData() appends more merchants to the data array.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.loading == false) {
        setTimeout(nextProps.fetchData,2000);
    }
```

And inside my MapView component -

```
{
    this.props.data.length > 0 && this.props.data.map(merchant => (
        <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{latitude: Number(merchant.latitude), longitude: Number(merchant.longitude)}}
            title={merchant.name}
            description={merchant.address}
            identifier={"" + merchant.id}
            key={merchant.id}
        />
    ))
}
```

**My problem:** Whenever I call fetchData(), the new markers are rendered. However, the whole map is rendered again. I do not want this kind of blinking behaviour.

I'd be very grateful for any kind of help/suggestions. Thanks in advance!

P.S. You can find the visual [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31779922/34214184-c2770e80-e5c7-11e7-99f5-3f6bd833501e.gif)

Comment: [why-did-you-update](https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update) might give you a hint why is your component updated and re-rendered

Comment: And there is a lifecycle event for React component [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) where you can control when you want component to update.

Comment: I'd probably help if we could see `fetchData` and the surrounding `<MapView>` tag with props.

Comment: I also need help with this

Comment: did you find any solution @Neal Karpe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom class component instead of `MapView.marker`, then use the `componentShouldUpdate()` function to specify if the marker needs to update under certain conditions.